# Rendering different components based on hook state using conditional rendering returning null

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to render three different components based upon the state stored in hooks.

The state gets sent upon a 'onSubmit' function, which takes the response and if it's successful sets 'submitted' as true, or 'error' as false.

However, when I'm attempting to do conditional rendering, where 'error === true', or 'submitted === true', and then the overall component if neither applies, it's just not showing the component at all.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
const WaitingListComponent = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    await axios.post("/api/waiting-list/addToList", {
      email: email
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setSubmitted(true)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(true)
      })
    }

    const errorComponent = () => {
      return (
        <form className="waiting-list-component-container" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <span className="waiting-list-success-span">
            <i className="fas fa-times-circle fa-3x waiting-list-error"></i>
            <p className="waiting-list-success-paragraph">Oops. Seems like there's been a problem. Please try again.</p>
            </span>
        </form>
      )
    }

    const successComponent = () => {
      return (
      <form className="waiting-list-component-container" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <span className="waiting-list-success-span">
          <i className="fas fa-check-circle fa-3x waiting-list-success"></i>
          <p className="waiting-list-success-paragraph">Thanks for signing up to our waiting list. A confirmation email is flying your way now.</p>
          </span>
      </form>
      )
    }

    const form = () => {
      return (
        <form className="waiting-list-component-container" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <h4 className="waiting-list-component-heading">Join our waiting list to get early access</h4>
          <p className="waiting-list-component-paragraph">Like the sound of us? Join our waiting list to get exclusive early access to our platform when we're ready to launch.</p>
          <input className="waiting-list-component-input" name="email" type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="janedoe@email.com" />
          <GeneralButton type="submit" text="Get access" />
        </form>
      )
    }

  return (
    <>
      { error === true ? errorComponent : submitted === true ? successComponent : form }
    </>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (
    <>
      { error ? errorComponent() : submitted ? successComponent() : form() }
    </>

  )
```

Comment: :) In your code you are using ```errorComponent()```, ```successComponent()```, ```form()``` as a callable instead of directly calling, that's why you were not getting any return. apart from that, wonderful code.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this?
I think this way may be a little more intuitive.

```js
if (error) return errorComponent();
if (submitted) return successComponent();
return form();
```